# Simple java program can not be run

Tags: java

I am trying to compile and run HelloWorld on linux machin with java version 1.6. I get  it compiled but can not run it. I know that the program is at least correct.

Can anybody tell me how to get the silly program run?

I know even this problem had been metioned several times but nowhere found the fix of that  problem. Compile command I used: `javac ExampleProgram.java`. 
Run Command I used: `java ExampleProgram`

```
//A Very Simple Example
class ExampleProgram {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("I'm a Simple Program");
  }
}
```

The error:

```
java -classpath . ExampleProgram
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: ExampleProgram : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: ExampleProgram.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: You are compiling and running with different version of java

Comment: That does not help me much how to fix the problem. When I check the version of java, it tells me: java version "1.6.0_35"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.10-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Your jre and jdk should be same version...

Comment: How to fix it that compiling and running can be issued with the same version?

Comment: check your javac version using `javac -version`

Comment: Thanks @Vishal. Now I checked java and javac versions. It was obvious that both are diffirent version 1.6 and 1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is compiled with JDK 1.7, but you are actually running it with an earlier version of Java.

If you are invoking the program in command line, type

```
java -version
```

to see which version of Java you are actually using.

Or, if you are using an editor like Eclipse, check out your Java settings.

Another solution is to use

```
javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 SimpleProgram.java
```

instead of

```
javac SimpleProgram.java
```

Comment: When I check the version of java, it tells me: java version "1.6.0_35" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.10-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964010/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-and-running-java-1-7-code-on-java-1-6/11964045#11964045 I answered a similar question a while ago

Comment: Can you delete the SimpleProgram.class file and try again with javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 SimpleProgram.java? It should work.

Comment: @su- OPs Classname is `class ExampleProgram`

Comment: I see. That's why. Thanks Smit. MMAB, as Smit pointed out, you were compiling class A and executing class B.